# Algorithm: two tables are in connection with ID, calculating a new table from them

Tags: c#, excel, algorithm, linq, key

I have two Excel tables for input.

The structure of the first one is like (first_table, fields: id, value, no primary key):

```
ID1 4  
ID1 5  
ID1 2  
ID2 3  
ID2 1  
ID3 1  
ID4 1  
ID4 3
```

etc till the end of the document (it's not determined)

The second one is like (second_table, fields: id, value, ID is primary key):

```
ID1 2  
ID2 5  
ID3 1  
ID4 2
```

etc till the end of the document (it's not determined)

I would like to create a new table (let's call it output_table) from these. The new table should contain the same fields: ID and value. In this new table I want to write each records from the first table keeping its sequence (it's very important, because it's in a timeline). The values should change according to the following conditions:
- ID's are in connection
- if the first_table.value is higher than or equals with the second_table.value, the output.value := second_table.value. And this point I would like to omit records under it with the same IDs (in the first table) and step to the next ID type.
- if the the second_table.value is higher than the first_table.value, then output_table.value := first_table.value and the reference of second_table.value := (second_table.value - first_table.value) for the next step (and if this case happens, I want to investigate the next record with the calculated reference till a new ID comes up from first_table, or the first condition will be true)

I could not figure out the proper algorithm for it, please help me! Thank you for your help!!
I'm working in C#, and I have already created list of (record) objects from the two input table. (so maybe Linq would help me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.

You may create a class (you could use a `Tuple<string, int>` instead, but it maybe easier to understand) for first_table and output table values.

```
public class MyDatas {
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

Imagine you have, from first_table, a List of `MyDatas`

And for second_table a `Dictionary<string, int>`

which seems reasonable.

then you create an empty list of `MyDatas` which is your output.

```
var table1 = new List<MyDatas>(<content of first_table>);
var table2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(<content of second_table>);
var output = new List<MyDatas>();

//good old foreach, this may be clearer than linq in this case.
foreach (var l1 in table1) {
  var id = l1.Id;
  //default : we take table 1 Value (if Id is not in table2 or table 2 value > table1 value
  var newData = new MyDatas{Id = id, Value = l1.Value};
  output.Add(newData);
  //id of table1 is not in table 2, go to next line.
  if (!table2.ContainsKey(id)) continue;


  //if table 1 value > = table 2 value => take table 2 value
  if (l1.Value >= table2[id])
     newData.Value = table2[id];
  //if  table 2 value => table 1 value, keep table 1 value for output and decrement table2 value
  else {
      table2[id] -= l1.Value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's OK, it works well. I have a further question: what do you suggest, if I would like to eliminate records from output, which (IDs) have already get as many values as it's possible (due to conditions) from the table2? To be clear, my output should be like: ID1-2, ID2-3, ID2-1, ID3-1, ID4-1, ID4-1

Comment: I’ll try to approach the problem from another perspective and be more specific. So, essentially, records in table1 mean empty (free) spaces. While records in table2 mean values (load) which we have to put in the free spaces, so many as it’s possible. If less free space are available for one ID than load value in table2, then we have to fill in every places (so it means the records with same IDs from table 1 simply goes to the output table).

Comment: If we have more free spaces (summing same IDs values) than the loads in table2, then we have to move in sequence in table1, and we fill as many spaces as we can with load. And when load runs out, but we still have free spaces, that records must not be inserted to the output table. And following by this logic the output table should be like in my previous comment.

Comment: @KNG got to go, I will try to look at that this afternoon ;)